# Get user's location for Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, flutter-web

I'm currently using the Flutter Geolocator Plugin to access user's location (latitude/longitude), but it seems like it does not work for the web yet. I tried to find something to retrieve the user's location in Flutter for web, but I couldn't find it.

Has anyone already tried/found something to do the job?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To be able to retrieve the position for the web part I had to use
https://pub.dev/packages/js to expose the JavaScript API and combine it with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API.

So here how it looks like :

1. First create a file (ex: locationJs.dart) to expose the JS function :

   ```
    @JS('navigator.geolocation') // navigator.geolocation namespace
    library jslocation; // library name can be whatever you want

    import "package:js/js.dart";

   @JS('getCurrentPosition') // Accessing method getCurrentPosition 
   from       Geolocation API
   external void getCurrentPosition(Function success(GeolocationPosition pos));

   @JS()
   @anonymous
   class GeolocationCoordinates {
     external double get latitude;
     external double get longitude;
     external double get altitude;
     external double get accuracy;
     external double get altitudeAccuracy;
     external double get heading;
     external double get speed;

   external factory GeolocationCoordinates(
     {double latitude,
     double longitude,
     double altitude,
     double accuracy,
     double altitudeAccuracy,
     double heading,
     double speed});
     }

   @JS()
   @anonymous
   class GeolocationPosition {
   external GeolocationCoordinates get coords;

   external factory GeolocationPosition({GeolocationCoordinates 
   coords});
   }
   ```
2. Call the newly created file

   ```
    import 'package:Shared/locationJs.dart';

     success(pos) {
        try {
          print(pos.coords.latitude);
          print(pos.coords.longitude);
          } catch (ex) {
           print("Exception thrown : " + ex.toString());
            }
        }

     _getCurrentLocation() {
         if (kIsWeb) {
           getCurrentPosition(allowInterop((pos) => success(pos)));
                   }
         }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot been looking for this

Comment: Can you help me please? Im getting the error: "NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'geolocation.getCurrentPosition'"

Comment: Hi.. this is great answer, and it works for me... can you provide me a guidance about the start the way you create locationJs.dart dan combine it with api js ?

Comment: This is not work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64411270/flutter-web-get-location-on-web-by-location-plugin