# getting user location in PWA flutter project

Tags: flutter, location, progressive-web-apps, flutter-web

I am trying to build PWA flutter project and I wanna get coordinate of user location, I have used package of location and mapbox_gl, but the problem is.. it takes so long to get the coordinate of the user... it doesn't happen when I build in apps project... is this because connection or something else?

Comment: you a trying to get current location of user,i suggest to use location or geolocator @uyhaW

Comment: Sorry about deleting the answer i think that is irrelevant,for flutter web it's kind of different,Try this ,it may help you,`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60209381/get-users-location-for-flutter-web` ,,                                                                                                                    `https://dev.to/aseemwangoo/flutter-web-and-location-2l1` @uyhaW